# scala + mongoDB how to?

Tags: scala, mongodb, sbt

1. I am following http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/current/setting_up.html in order to use MongoDB with scala.
2. I am new to sbt as well. The above starting up guide says:

> 1.1.5. Setting up SBT
>
> Finally, you can add Casbah to SBT by adding the following to your
>   project file:
>
> val casbah = "com.mongodb.casbah" %% "casbah" % "2.1.5.0" The double
>   percentages (%%) is not a typo—it tells SBT that the library is
>   crossbuilt and to find the appropriate version for your project’s
>   Scala version. If you prefer to be explicit you can use this instead:
>
> // Scala 2.8.0 val casbah = "com.mongodb.casbah" % "casbah_2.8.0" %
>   "2.1.5.0" // Scala 2.8.1 val casbah = "com.mongodb.casbah" %
>   "casbah_2.8.1" % "2.1.5.0" // Scala 2.9.0.1 (don't use Scala
>   2.9.0.final; 2.9.0.1 contains critical fixes) val casbah = "com.mongodb.casbah" % "casbah_2.9.0-1" % "2.1.5.0" Don’t forget to
>   reload the project and run sbt update afterwards to download the
>   dependencies (SBT doesn’t check every build like Maven).

My question is what does first line mean, "adding following line to your project file".

My understanding about adding dependancy is:

1. add following line to build.sbt file

   ```
   dependancies += "com.mongodb.casbah" % "casbah_2.9.0-1" % "2.1.5.0"
   ```
2. Then do sbt update

But, when I do sbt update, I get following error:

```
[error] {file:/Users/hrishikeshparanjape/git-public/ws/}default-1efcb1/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.mongodb.casbah#casbah_2.9.0-1;2.1.5.0: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 26, 2012 9:32:59 PM
```

In short, I did not understand that getting started page.

**EDIT**

my build.sbt file:

```
name := "ws"

version := "0.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.mongodb.casbah" % "casbah_2.9.0-1" % "2.1.5.0"
```

My directory structure(basicmost nothing added yet)

```
ws
-build.sbt
```

Comment: Adding the line under 1. to your build.sbt should be enough. Are you running in to  any problem when doing that?

Comment: no it does not work please check the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to add a resolver to your build.sbt file.

```
resolvers += "snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

resolvers += "releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools"
```

More info on sbt can be found [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Welcome). Going through it is very helpfull in understanding the basics of sbt:

Comment: yep that what I needed. BTW.. scala-tools does not exist anymore, new repo is hosted by sonatype

Answer (score 1):

A lot of time has passed but I would like to share an update for those, who may search for Scala MongoDB client library.

We have published the Scala library that wraps original mongodb-core in the Scala manner. The API is much more convenient that the mongo-scala-driver from MongoDB for Scala and fully asynchronous. Instead of callbacks we expose Futures and for those with more sophisticated needs the RXScala observables.

If you'r using Play Framwork 2.4 there is a module with ready to use formatters for Json: https://github.com/evojam/play-mongodb-driver
With the Play Framework module it's pretty straightforward to start, like few minutes to get working code.

This way MongoDB is nice and easy to use in Scala. We have provided a comparison of the sample query execution is in our [blog post](http://evojam.com/blog/2015/6/15/async-mongodb-driver-for-scala-open-source-by-evojam) about the driver on site.